# php explode an array (one column) and put it into mysql (different column)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have to get some pictures from a table like this (two columns  - id e foto):
1 - img1
2 - img2
3 - img3
4 - img4
ecc...

i get this information from a query like this:

```
$query_foto="SELECT foto FROM foto_annunci WHERE codice_annuncio = 'paolo-146110'";
$rs_foto=mysql_query("$query_foto",$dbh) or die("Errore query database foto: " . mysql_error());
while($result3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_foto)){
$foto1 = $result3['0']['foto'];
$foto2 = $result3['1']['foto'];
$foto3 = $result3['2']['foto'];
$foto4 = $result3['3']['foto'];
```

then i have to put all this images into another table, table have 5 columns already written:

id - name - country - foto1 - foto2 - foto3 - foto4

at the moment i trying this but only last records has benn saved into db in the first column:

```
$query="UPDATE annunci_x90 SET 
foto1 = '$foto1',
foto2= '$foto2',
foto3= '$foto3',
foto4= '$foto4'

WHERE id=41";

$result=mysql_query("$query",$dbh) or die("Errore query database: " . mysql_error());
```

so my problems is to get images from first table and put those images into the secon table ( UPDATE query) in columns foto1 - foto2 - foto3.

how can i get it?
thanks

Comment: Do you do the update in the while-loop or after that? For your logic to work it should be in the while-loop. If you put it after the loop, only the last record would be updated in the db.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did it, but not working, only last data in the db

Comment: Since the 'WHERE id=41' is hard coded only that record will be updated.

Comment: i would update 4 records of one row not only one record of one row. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query_foto="SELECT foto FROM foto_annunci WHERE codice_annuncio = 'paolo-146110'";
$rs_foto=mysql_query("$query_foto",$dbh) or die("Errore query database foto: " . mysql_error());
$foto = array();
while($result3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_foto)){
$foto[] = $result3['foto'];
}

$query = "UPDATE annunci_x90 SET
foto1='" . isset($foto[0]) ? $foto[0] : '' . "',
foto2='" . isset($foto[1]) ? $foto[1] : '' . "',
foto3='" . isset($foto[2]) ? $foto[2] : '' . "',
foto4='" . isset($foto[3]) ? $foto[3] : '' . "'
WHERE 
id='41'
";
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but i got a problem: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'paolo-146110-3LOGOsconti2013_a.jpg' at line 1. Do you know how to run it? thanks

Comment: hy man, i change it like: foto1= '$foto[0]',
and it works. i would like to know your way however you solve me a good problem. Thanks!!!!!